# Infer the type of a wrapper from wrapped function

Tags: typescript, type-inference

The objective is to infer the type of a wrapper from wrapped function, i.e. return type from parameter type.

I couldn't achieve this with `infer`:

```
function wrap<T extends ((...args: any[]) => any) & { flag?: string }>(wrapped: T extends infer R ? R : never): T {
        let wrapper = function () {
            // ...
            return wrapped(...arguments);
        } as T;

        wrapper.flag = wrapped.flag;

        return wrapper;
}

let wrapped = (a: number, b: number) => `${a}{b}`;

// wrapper is ((...args: any[]) => any) & { flag?: string }
// should be ((a: number, b: number) => string & { flag?: string }
let wrapper = wrap(wrapped);

// foo is any
// should be string
let foo = wrapper('invalid');
```

How can this be done in this case without specifying wrapper type explicitly?

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAeAKogUwA8oCwATAZ0QAoaA6R9VAc0oC5F0wBPAbQC6ASkQBeAHxdeQ8TQBQiFBkyYC5TvgBkiAN6JgAG3QsA-J0pRUMMC0QBfIRsTa9h42cQWrN+7oWIDAiglLFVUMX1waHgkGhEdf0UAeiTERnpExFQgkFQkNFC1BiZWEABbMihKIQBufzsuai1dfSNTc0trWzs6-wKVAlR6N1tREIHyYbbexWyoXPzlMLq7OTlA4P7VcgiadE4wcoAjQYAaRCOD48GRCUQAAwASHXQ7HSO7e96U8bDEGGodHSzDYnG4-GEYkk4JELla7g63m6ch+lAAFnAQAYdidaHsrmUTqhzpdEIdCTcoZ5Oj44SMPF4uvZ1kFfoMIv0aFs1LU1j9gHA4P9qOCUal0ZjsRcCNSkSzggKhWNuagaAByawAN3QBhg5DVtSAA)?  Let me know if that meets your needs and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Exactly, thanks a lot, you're helpful as always. Glad to see it works without `infer` magic, still curious why I it couldn't make it work before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a value of type `T extends infer R ? R : never`, the compiler will almost certainly be unable to infer anything useful for `T` (since it will tend to defer evaluating such a conditional type until after its too late for `T` to be inferred).  Since that type is essentially equivalent to `T`, we'll just use `T` in what follows.

I think the `wrap()` signature and implementation should look like this:

```
function wrap<T extends ((...args: any[]) => any)>(
  wrapped: T & { flag?: string }): T & { flag?: string } {
  let wrapper = function () {
    // ...
    return wrapped(...arguments);
  } as T & { flag?: string };

  wrapper.flag = wrapped.flag;

  return wrapper;
}
```

That is, we're just going to use the generic parameter `T` to represent the function type, and leave the `{flag?: string}` as a separate non-generic object type with which `T` will be intersected.  The reason why you need to do something like this has to do with assignability rules for optional properties:

In TypeScript, an object type *missing* a property is considered assignable to an object with an *optional* property of any type.  For example, the type `{foo: string}` is  assignable to the type `{foo: string, bar?: number}`.  If you have a generic type `T extends {foo: string, bar?: number}`, it's possible for `T` to be `{foo: string}`, entirely missing the `bar` property.

In your case, if you have a generic type `T extends ((...args: any[])=>any) & {flag?: string}`, and pass in a function without a known `flag` property as an inference site for `T`, the compiler will infer `T` as just being the function type without the `flag` property. And then the function output has no `flag` property either, and you're sad.

In order to ensure that the compiler interprets both the input and the output of the function as having an optional `flag` property, we need to include it explicitly in both the input and the output, and not give the compiler a chance to lose track of it.

Okay; hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAeAKogUwA8oCwATAZ0QAoaA6R9VAc0oC5F0wBPAbQC6ASkQBeAHxdeQ8TQBQiFBkyYC5TvgBkiAN6JgAG3QsA-J0pRUMMC0QBfIRsTa9h42cQWrN+7oWIDAiglLFVUMX1waHgkGhEdf0UAeiTERnpExFQgkFQkNFC1BiZWEABbMihKIQBufzsuai1dfSNTc0trWzs6-wKVAlR6N1tREIHyYbbexWyoXPzlMLq7OTlA4P7VcgiadE4wcoAjQYAaRCOD48GRCUQAAwASHXQ7HSO7e7qN8bCI-poWzUtXWQX0cDg-yWgxoAEZzgAmEGIORAA)